# Neo4j design choice: relationships vs nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm dealing with the following situation: many trips exist between many cities. Both have various properties. E.g the cities have a name and an amount of trips that passed them, whereas trips have a distance and time.

What is *'best practise'* in Neo4j?

a) Add all cities and trips as nodes, and connect the trips to the start and end nodes by means of 'STARTED_AT' and 'ENDS_IN' relations.

**or**

b) Add only cities as a node, and represent each of the trips as a relation between 2 nodes. This means there are many of the same relations between nodes, where the only difference is that they have other properties.

Information that might be useful: we only need to do all kinds of queries. No insertion needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the trips a predefined list? Or are you able to take a trip from any city, to any other connected city? If the later, it may be more performent to dynamically calculate time/distance at query time, as caching those values would grow your db exponentially.

Comment: @Tezra it is a predefined list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue it's better to store trips as nodes because relationship properties cannot be indexed, and it will be slow to do more complex queries (like find shortest route by time) So if you are searching for trips by ID or something, you will need to store them as nodes.

On the other hand, an argument can be made for using relationships, because then you can take full advantage of [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html)'s weighted graph search functions.

A good way to decide if something should be a node or relation, is to ask yourself "are there any other relations that would make sense here?" If you are talking about if two cities are connected, a relationship makes more since because they either are or are not. If you are talking about road trips though, the trip can pass through multiple cities, can have participants in the trip (or groups there of) and can have an owner. In that case, for future flexibility, nodes will be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it really depends on how you model these trips, lets assume we can generalize this as (city)-[trip]->(city). Notice that neo4j's relations always has a direction so we can go on adding an unlimited number of trips between cities without having to redefine each city for each trip -- this actually answers (a) by the way, we don't need to define where it starts and ends the relation does all that work for you.

'This means there are many of the same relations between nodes' <<- on this note, if you need to differ each trip based on the time the trip was taken you can add the date/timestamp in the relationship property or you can go with a time tree (see [Mark Needham's Article on that here](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) and [Graphgrid's take](https://www.graphgrid.com/modeling-time-series-data-with-neo4j/))
Hope this helps.